# How can I determine what option is selected on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu of values:

```
            <select class="notifications-dropdown">
                <option value="val1">Val4</option>
                <option value="val2">Val3</option>
                <option value="val3">Val2</option>
                <option value="val4">Val1</option>
            </select>
```

I want to make it so when a user selects one of the options from the dropdown, that option has a '`selected`' attribute toggled on. For example, if a user clicks the dropdown and selects Val3 then the DOM should change as follows:

```
            <select class="notifications-dropdown">
                <option value="val1">Val4</option>
                <option value="val2" selected>Val3</option>
                <option value="val3">Val2</option>
                <option value="val4">Val1</option>
            </select>
```

I am not sure what jQuery event to listen for to know when a user selects an option though. I tried listening for a `change` event on the `.notifications-dropdown` but the generated event object does not give me any indication about which option was selected. How can I determine what option is selected on a dropdown?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).val()` in `change` event?

Comment: Your options values and text don't match, just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track with the `change` event. But that is the thing, the `change` event just tells you that the field/option selected has changed, it, and any other event listener, will not provide a value.

To get the value, you will need to reference jQuery like so:

```
$('.notifications-dropdown option:selected').text();
```

or to get the value of the option selected, you can reference it like so:

```
$('.notifications-dropdown option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on your select list.

```js
$('.notifications-dropdown').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="notifications-dropdown">
    <option value="val1">Val4</option>
    <option value="val2">Val3</option>
    <option value="val3">Val2</option>
    <option value="val4">Val1</option>
</select>
```

`this` when used inside of a jQuery callback is the element which the event occurred on.

Comment: Can I achieve this same effect without referring to the this identifer? My framework overrides the this binding in the jQuery callback.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4: How is that possible? jQuery provides the `this` value to the handler; are you intercepting it? Why would you override `this`? That seems incredibly confusing and frankly is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track:

```
// on Dom-ready
$(function() {
    // bind the 'change' event
    $('.notifications-dropdown').change(function() {
        // $(this).val() will have the selected value
        alert($(this).val());
    }).change(); // fire it once on page-load if you need to do anything based on the current value
});
```

The user's action of selecting a new option will modify the DOM element's `selected` attribute -- you don't need to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code on a jquery change event. Assume, select tag has `id="selectId"`

To Read Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val();
```

To Set Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val('newValue');
```

To Read Selected Text

```
$('#selectId>option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.
>
> > The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

```
$('.notifications-dropdown').change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```